# magento slideshow disappear when I edit the CMS home page title from "Home page" to something else

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I am facing this strange problem with my website that if change the home page title from "Home page" to something else, it will kill my home page slideshow. I am at the same time amused and perplexed and any help would be highly appreciated.

Website URL: www.letterfloret.com

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the title "HOme Page".

Go to Admin Panel -> CMS -> Pages -> Home Page-> Content->

Remove the Home page title over there , afterward click on the Show/Hide editor button and write the following

```
`<html>
</html>`
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: I did ditto what you said. but did not work. Can you suggest something else?